# Laravel limit by ID

Tags: database, laravel, controller, limit

I have the code below to get all of my messages from my database. All messages contain a room_ID. I want to have the most recent 20 messages of each room when I go to localhost:8000/api/messages. Is it possible and how?

```php
public function showAll()
{
    $messages = Message::all();

    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $message->user;
        $message->room;
    }

    return response()->json($messages);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Flat and simple, you would just do this for each of the rooms:

```
$messages = Message::where('room_id', $room->id)->orderBy('date_column')
    ->paginate(20)->get();
```

This ofcourse can be simplified if you setup your relations properly.